# How to return sorted distinct values in console?

Tags: r

I would like to return a list in the R console of all unique values for a dataframe column. However, I also wanted the list to be sorted but I'm unable to do this.

```
df %>% distinct(var)
```

This works fine, but when I try doing:

```
df %>% sort(distinct(var))
```

It gives me this error message

> Error in distinct(home_street) : object 'home_street' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the unique values, then sort by the variable column, then use `pull` to get just the vector.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  distinct(cyl) %>% 
  arrange(cyl) %>% 
  pull()

#[1] 4 6 8
```

Or in base R:

```
sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))
```